# C++ script in Python

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm relatively new to the ros system.. I'm trying to install the sick_tim3xx-groovy package on my ros system but the package is written in C++ whereas my system is in Python.

Is there anyway to install the package without re-writting it or am I fresh outta luck?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63566/c++-script-in-python/) by [SuperRedRobin92](https://answers.ros.org/users/4984/superredrobin92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @SuperRedRobin92,

mixing nodes written in Python and nodes written in C++ is no problem in ROS, since each node is a separate process that communicates with other nodes over network messages. Simply follow the instructions on the [sick_tim3xx wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sick_tim3xx); the driver should publish [sensor_msgs/LaserScan](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) messages on the `/scan` topic. Simply subscribe to the `/scan` topic from your Python node and do whatever you want to do with the messages you get.

If you have any further questions, please comment on this answer or open a new question.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4